# How to align vis-line bar and the left side

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I need to make vis-line bigger (like 10px) and the vis-box left 10px as well so that the vis-line and vis-box can align left correctly just like one vertical line

```
.vis-item.vis-line { 
  position: absolute; 
  border-width: 10px; 
  border-color: red; 
}

.vis-item.vis-box {
   border-width: 1;
   text-align: left !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
   border-left-width: 10px;
   border-color: red;
}

var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

var items = new vis.DataSet([
 {id: 4, className:'item4', content: 'item 4', start: '2016-01-16'},
 {id: 5, className:'item5', content: 'item 5', start: '2016-02-23'},
 {id: 6, className:'item6', content: 'item 6', start: '2016-03-27'}
 ]);

 var options = {
// showCurrentTime: true,
 align: 'left',
 orientation: {axis: 'both', item: 'top'}, 
 height: 400,
 margin: {
     axis: 100
}
};
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

see the url https://jsfiddle.net/gbdjbdhv/4/ but vis-line is 5px left than the vis-box left side. I need advice on how to make the vis-line and vis-box left side can align vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in the first next release, see https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/1695